# Is there a way to get from a byte array to audio?

Tags: audio, encoding, byte, .lib

I want to get the audio files of .lib files of a game. I heard converting the .lib into an byte array is a good first step, where I'm now at, but I don't know what to do know.

***Is there a method for doing this?***

Small part of the array:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: sure ... read in the file as a binary file which may have a different api call depending on the language you are coding in ...  update your question to specify the language ...  you will need to discover where the audio begins and ends in the file ... if the audio is stereo the data will be interleaved left  right left right as you iterate across the data ...  be aware CD quality audio has a bit depth of 16 bits meaning a single audio sample ( point on the raw audio curve ) consumes 16 bits of memory so will be stored across two consecutive bytes of data .. master this reading a WAV file first

Comment: What does "get the audio files of .lib files" mean? What's a .lib file?